# Fill in the missing number in this unique sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence, computer-puzzle

My friend Ed woke up this morning to find his website defaced. Upon the now altered web page, he found this number sequence:

$237,\ 3566,\ 57069,\ \color{green}{???},\ 14600926,\ 233811181$

One of the numbers is missing, can you figure out what it could be?

---

<sup>Note: the story is fictional and can be used as a hint. Additional hints may be added if the puzzle remains unsolved.</sup>

Comment: 404 ? Not found...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing number is:

> 847341

> Convert each number to it's hexadecimal equivalent to get a word. 237 in Hex is ED, 3566 is DEE, 57069 is DEED, 14600926 is DECADE, and 233811181 is DEFACED.
>  Each number keeps the previous letters but adds one more, while still making a word. That means the missing number has to either add A or C to DEED (because DECADE is DEED with an A and a C added.
>  The only 5 letter word I could create from DEED + A or C was CEDED, which converted from hex to decimal came out to 847341.
>  (My first answer was ADDED, before I realized I added a D and removed an E...)

Comment: That is correct! Very impressive, I expected it would take much longer.

Comment: I was lucky, I had a professor use 233811181 in a lesson about conversions because of it's prime number status; probably wouldn't have remembered it if not for the comment about the story having a hint.

Comment: That's very interesting. I didn't realize it was prime, but of course that does come up when you Google the number. The other rot13(frira yrggre bcgvbaf jrer npprqrq naq rssnprq).